# INSERT succeeds but all inserted values become NULL

Tags: mysql, insert

I tired to execute an insert directly from phpMyAdmin as follows:

```
INSERT INTO oracle.PLAYLIST_MUSIC ( TID,
                ID,
                STATUS,
                CREATED_BY,
                CREATED_DATE,
                UPDATED_BY,
                UPDATED_DATE,
                ORDER
            )
VALUES(TID = 56919,
       ID = 115948,
       STATUS = '1',
       CREATED_BY = 15217,
       CREATED_DATE = NOW(),
       UPDATED_BY = 15217,
       UPDATED_DATE = NOW(),
       ORDER = 0)
```

The SQL executed successfully, however I found that all the inserted values became NULL, including the system generated values like `NOW()`.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: please post the create-statement of the table (using phpmyadmin's export-tab). Also avoid using reserved words like "order" as column name without passing it inside backticks, as this could lead to unwanted behaviour. And last: You use UPDATE-syntax for an INSERT. Look at the MySQL-Manual for how to write the VALUES-part of an INSERT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your insert syntax is wrong, using `column=value` in the `values` clause doesn't do what you think it does.

Try:

```
INTO oracle.PLAYLIST_MUSIC ( TID,
                ID,
                STATUS,
                CREATED_BY,
                CREATED_DATE,
                UPDATED_BY,
                UPDATED_DATE,
                `ORDER`
            )
VALUES(56919,
       115948,
       '1',
       15217,
       NOW(),
       15217,
       NOW(),
       0)
```

The values must be put in the same order as the column names appear in the `insert` statement.

It would probably be a good idea to quote the `order` column, since that's a reserved word.

I'm guessing the nulls come from the fact that the columns aren't bound to anything in the values clause, causing them to be null. And `null = any value` evaluates to null:

```
mysql> select null=1 ;
+--------+
| null=1 |
+--------+
|   NULL |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But that's just a guess about what is actually happening, I'm surprised that parsed at all.

Comment: I'm **really** suprised that MySQL didn't reject the original syntax. But it's probably again one of those things where MySQL tries to be clever and assumes it knows what the user "intended".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: with table `foo(a int, b int)`, the following works on MySQL: `insert into foo(a,b) values (42,a)` and inserts `(42,42)`. I guess that makes some kind of sense.

Comment: I was also surprised that the parser didnt blame me. 
I mixed up the syntax of 
`INSERT INTO <table> SET <COL> = <value>...`
with 
`INSERT INTO <table> VALUE( <value>,...);`

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO oracle.PLAYLIST_MUSIC 
SET
       TID = 56919,
       ID = 115948,
       STATUS = '1',
       CREATED_BY = 15217,
       CREATED_DATE = NOW(),
       UPDATED_BY = 15217,
       UPDATED_DATE = NOW(),
       ORDER = 0;
```